# Choco 4: Constrain domain of variable to equal a set of values

Tags: java, choco

I have the following array `S` of `IntVar[]`:

```
IntVar[] S = model.intVarArray("Flights Schedule", 18, 0, 19);
```

I also have the following `ArrayList` of `Integer`, called `fromHome`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> fromHome = [1, 2, 4];
```

`fromHome` is derived later in the program.

I want to constrain the domain of `S[0]` to contain only the values in `fromHome` and nothing else. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this using the `member` constraint as follows:

```
model.member(S[0], from_home).post();
```